# How to set z-index on hover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

How can I set the z-index on hover of an img element? When the mouse pointer is outside of the img, the z-index must be 0, otherwise, it should be 9.

I do know how to set it, but not how to change it on hover.

```
$('#content img').click(function () {
    $(this).css("z-index", "99")
});
```

Comment: Why answer the question with another question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#content img').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css("z-index", "9")
});

$('#content img').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css("z-index", "0")
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A css-only solution:

```
 #content img{
   z-index:0;
 }

 #content img:hover{
   z-index:9;
 }
```

Comment: To the editor: the semicolon is not neccessary, but thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$('#content img').hover( 
   function() { 
     $(this).css("z-index", "99")
   },
   function() { 
     $(this).css("z-index", "0")
   });
```